# How to use setState in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

In the follow code, I thought the text should update to the new one after 3 seconds:

https://jsfiddle.net/smrfcr9x/1/

```
var Component = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.span(null, "hello " + this.props.text);
  }

});

var aComponent = React.render(

  React.createElement(Component, {
    text: "abcd"
  }),

  document.getElementById("app")

);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("now setting state");
  aComponent.setState({
    text: "lmno"
  });
}, 3000);
```

How is it actually done?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setProps` to replace `setState`.

Please notice the warning in console from react.js:

> Warning: setProps(...) and replaceProps(...) are deprecated. Instead, call render again at the top level.

You may follow that warning.

EDIT:
Sorry for haven't said it clearly just now.
Using `setProps` to replace `setState` can do correctly what you want. But the method `setProps` has been deprecated and will show the warning above. So I think you should follow the waring, once you want to change the props, rerender the component.
You read the text from props not state in the component, so it won't work if you set the state.

EDIT2:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return React.DOM.span(null, "hello " + this.props.text);
    }
});

var renderComponent = function(text){
    React.render(
        React.createElement(Component, {
            text: text
        }),
        document.getElementById("app")
    );
}
renderComponent('abcd')
setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("now setting state");
      renderComponent('lmno')
}, 3000);
```

I'm sorry for not knowing how to share code in jsfiddle. This code work fine in it.

Comment: it works after I use `setProps`, but then it is deprecated?  then how should it be done?

Comment: I think you can wrap the `React.render` in a function, and pass `text` as a param. You can call this function every time you want to change the `text`, and it render component for you.

Comment: wrap the original `React.render`? No? Can you put in the jsfiddle?

Comment: wow... you create yet another component?  That's sounds heavy...   (by the way, you can click the "Update" link in JSFiddle and it will give you a new URL)

Comment: It just create another v-dom, I think it doesn't cost a lot. Thanks for teaching me :)

Comment: by the way, I am trying another example and setState works... see https://jsfiddle.net/smrfcr9x/5/   in this example, `setState` actually works

Comment: Dose the component also do the same as this one with getting `text` from `this.props`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get it.  The code to needs to set a state, and in `render`, use `this.state` instead of `this.props`:

https://jsfiddle.net/smrfcr9x/7/

```
var Component = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      text: this.props.text,
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.span(null, "hello " + this.state.text);
  }

});
```

Comment: Yep,that's a good way if the only purpose of props is to init the state.Good job~